# Advanced Url Provider and 404 error page

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have activated the Advanced Url Provider and a 404 error page in DNN 7.4.2. Works so far.

But: I deleted a page (also from the recycle bin) from the third level, let's say the Url was http://www.example.org/Level1/Level2/deletedPage - When I enter that Url now, I would expect that the 404 error page is displayed (as it is when I enter http://www.example.org/xxx/yyy/zzz) - but no, the parent page is displayed (http://www.example.org/Level1/Level2), with the Url of the deleted page, and in the IIS log file I find a http response status 200.

Any ideas?

Happy DNNing!
Michael

Comment: Try to delete browser's cache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. DNN takes the rest of the Url as query string parameters which could be used by a module, and the page does not "know" if that is needed or not.

In this example: As no page is available under

```
http://www.example.org/Level1/Level2/deletedPage
```

but a page is there under

```
http://www.example.org/Level1/Level2
```

it could be that a module needs or reacts to the querystring

```
?deletedPage
```

which is displayed as

```
http://www.example.org/Level1/Level2/deletedPage
```

by the Url provider. Therfore the behaviour is correct. An explanation can be found [here](https://www.40fingers.net/Portals/0/Manual%2040Fingers%20404%20re-direct.pdf), chapter "DNN pages & 404s" at the end of page 1 and beginning of page 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would think when you delete a page, an custom Urls for that page would get deleted, but check the `TabUrls` table to see if there is an entry for /Level1/Level2/deletedPage in there.

Comment: Nothing in the TabUrls - I already checked that. In fact I added that Url to the TabUrls, with a response of 404. Did not change the behaviour...